# VBA - Alphabetical Sorting Issue with Moving Referenced Rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, reference

I have a sheet which contains a list of names. Next to each name is a number associated with that person. I have code to add people to this list and sort this list once again in alphabetical order. In many other sheets in that workbook, I reference the number to place that number inside a cell. When I add a person, creating a new line actually updates that code in the line automatically:

```
='Employee List'!B4
```

but once I sort the list, thihngs don't update. If the number in B4 was moved down to B5 becasue I added a new line, the code would read

```
='Employee List'!B5
```

automatically, but if when sorted into alphabetical order it was shoved up to `B3`, it would not updated. I am inputting all these formulas thorugh VBA and tried using the workbook function

```
=INDIRECT("'Employee List'!B4")
```

but it, as well only applies to the cell. I want it to stay with the name of the person. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). Use VLOOKUP, when you need to find things in a table or a range by row.

Comment: I have been doing so much more and things way more complicated that I completely forgot about vlookup and how useful it is. Thank you!!